# Fabricjs isolate object count by color

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I have a counter that tallies the total number of objects on canvas, but I want to isolate it to count by object color. Can `canvas.getObjects().length;` get objects by color?

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var iconTriangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 62.5,
  height: 50,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fill: "green"
});
icon = iconTriangle;
canvas.add(icon);
//disable icon & hide when hovering over existing icon
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(obj) {
  iconTriangle.set('opacity', 0);
  icon = null;
  canvas.renderAll()
});
//restor icon & unhide
canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
  iconTriangle.set('opacity', 1);
  icon = iconTriangle;
  canvas.renderAll()
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
  icon.top = obj.e.y - 80;
  icon.left = obj.e.x - 10;
  canvas.renderAll()
});
canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
  icon.top = -100;
  icon.left = -100;
  canvas.renderAll()
});
//place icon and count each by type
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
  var count = canvas.getObjects().length;
  document.getElementById("greentally").value = count;
  document.getElementById("yellowtally").value = count;
  document.getElementById("redtally").value = count;
  canvas.add(icon.clone());
  canvas.renderAll();
});
//set icon type
function iconSet() {
  if (document.getElementById("green").checked == true) {
    iconTriangle.setFill("green");
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.trigger('object:modified', {
      target: iconTriangle
    });

  } else if (document.getElementById("yellow").checked == true) {
    iconTriangle.setFill("yellow");
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.trigger('object:modified', {
      target: iconTriangle
    });
  } else if (document.getElementById("red").checked == true) {
    iconTriangle.setFill("red");
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.trigger('object:modified', {
      target: iconTriangle
    });
  }
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tally {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  left: 255px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>

<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="green" onclick="iconSet()" />Green &emsp;
<input class="tally" disabled id="greentally" type="text" value="0">
<br>
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="yellow" onclick="iconSet()" /> Yellow &emsp;
<input class="tally" disabled id="yellowtally" type="text" value="0">
<br>
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="red" onclick="iconSet()" /> red &emsp;
<input class="tally" disabled id="redtally" type="text" value="0">
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To count objects with a specific color (or any other property) is easy since you get the array of all objects on canvas via `canvas.getObjects()` - then you just filter those you're after  via `filter()`. I've introduced a `getObjectsBy(fn)` helper function in my snippet for that.

That said, your code has several other issues worth addressing:

- making `icon` a copy reference to `iconTriangle` may look neat at first, but really is pointless and error-prone, e.g. you had to write separate logic to hide the copy and you have to keep an eye on whether it is `null` when you actually need it. This is the reason you're getting those `Cannot set property 'top' of null`. In my snippet, I'm creating a new icon via a factory-like `addIcon()`, which is as easy to use as `clone()` but is also much easier to maintain.
- `mouse:up` event is triggered not just when you click on the canvas, but also when you click on objects, so you end up creating unnecessary icons each time you move something around. In my snippet, I'm using an early return in the `mouse:up` listener to fix this.
- `iconSet()` seems like a good place to introduce a helper function to make it more concise. Also, storing color in a separate variable helps decouple icon creation from the `iconTriangle`.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var currentColor;
var defaultIcon = {
  width: 62.5,
  height: 50,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center'
};
var iconTriangle = new fabric.Triangle(defaultIcon);
setColor('green');
canvas.add(iconTriangle);
//disable icon & hide when hovering over existing icon
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(obj) {
  iconTriangle.set('opacity', 0);
  canvas.renderAll();
});
//restor icon & unhide
canvas.on('mouse:out', function(e) {
  // if 'target' is null, means mouse is out of canvas
  if (e.target) {
    iconTriangle.set('opacity', 1);
  } else {
    iconTriangle.left = -100;
    iconTriangle.top = -100;
  }
  canvas.renderAll();
});
//move pointer icon
canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
  iconTriangle.top = obj.e.y - 80;
  iconTriangle.left = obj.e.x - 10;
  canvas.renderAll();
});

//count each by type and place new icon
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(e) {
  if (e.target) {
    return
  }
  var red = getObjectsBy((obj) => obj.fill === 'red').length;
  var green = getObjectsBy((obj) => obj.fill === 'green').length;
  var yellow = getObjectsBy((obj) => obj.fill === 'yellow').length;
  document.getElementById("greentally").value = green;
  document.getElementById("yellowtally").value = yellow;
  document.getElementById("redtally").value = red;
  addIcon(e.e.x - 10, e.e.y - 80, currentColor);
});
//set icon type
function iconSet() {
  if (document.getElementById("green").checked == true) {
    setColor('green');
  } else if (document.getElementById("yellow").checked == true) {
    setColor('yellow');
  } else if (document.getElementById("red").checked == true) {
    setColor('red');
  }
}
function setColor (color) {
  currentColor = color;
  iconTriangle.setFill(currentColor);
  canvas.renderAll();
}
function getObjectsBy (fn) {
  return canvas.getObjects().filter(fn)
}
function addIcon (x, y, color) {
  var icon = new fabric.Triangle(defaultIcon);
  icon.setFill(color);
  icon.left = x;
  icon.top = y;
  canvas.add(icon);
  canvas.renderAll();
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tally {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  left: 255px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>

<input checked name="iconType" type="radio" id="green" onclick="iconSet()" />Green &emsp;
<input class="tally" disabled id="greentally" type="text" value="0">
<br>
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="yellow" onclick="iconSet()" /> Yellow &emsp;
<input class="tally" disabled id="yellowtally" type="text" value="0">
<br>
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="red" onclick="iconSet()" /> red &emsp;
<input class="tally" disabled id="redtally" type="text" value="0">
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 1):

Using a custom helper function I was able to count and filter by the color. You can extend function to handle more complicated filter like by shape type and color. In addition, you might want to implement a cache mechanism to prevent it from recounting every time.

```
     function canvasCount(canvas) {
          var obj = canvas.getObjects();
          var res = {};

          for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
                if (!obj[i].type) continue; // skip main canvas obj 

                // get the shapes color
                var color = obj[i].fill;

                // adds color key if not already in obj
                if (!res[color]) res[color] = 0;
                // increments color each by one
                res[color]++;

                // Length of all yellow triangles 
                // res.yellow
          }
          return res;
    }
```

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var iconTriangle = new fabric.Triangle({
  width: 62.5,
  height: 50,
  originX: 'center',
  originY: 'center',
  fill: "green"
});
icon = iconTriangle;
canvas.add(icon);
//disable icon & hide when hovering over existing icon
canvas.on('mouse:over', function(obj) {
  iconTriangle.set('opacity', 0);
  icon = null;
  canvas.renderAll()
});
//restor icon & unhide
canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
  iconTriangle.set('opacity', 1);
  icon = iconTriangle;
  canvas.renderAll()
});

canvas.on('mouse:move', function(obj) {
  icon.top = obj.e.y - 80 ;
  icon.left = obj.e.x - 10 ;
  canvas.renderAll()
});
canvas.on('mouse:out', function(obj) {
  icon.top = -100;
  icon.left = -100;
  canvas.renderAll()
});
//place icon and count each by type
canvas.on('mouse:up', function(obj) {
  var count = canvasCount(canvas);
  
  
  document.getElementById("greentally").value = count.green || 0;
  document.getElementById("yellowtally").value = count.yellow || 0 ;
  document.getElementById("redtally").value = count.red || 0;
  canvas.add(icon.clone());
  canvas.renderAll();
});
//set icon type
function iconSet() {
  if (document.getElementById("green").checked == true) {
    iconTriangle.setFill("green");
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.trigger('object:modified', {
      target: iconTriangle
    });
  } else if (document.getElementById("yellow").checked == true) {
    iconTriangle.setFill("yellow");
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.trigger('object:modified', {
      target: iconTriangle
    });
  } else if (document.getElementById("red").checked == true) {
    iconTriangle.setFill("red");
    canvas.renderAll();
    canvas.trigger('object:modified', {
      target: iconTriangle
    });
  }
}

function canvasCount(canvas) {
      var obj = canvas.getObjects();
      var res = {};

      for (var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
            if (!obj[i].type) continue; // skip main canvas obj 

            // get the shapes color
            var color = obj[i].fill;
            
            // adds color key if not already in obj
            if (!res[color]) res[color] = 0;
            // increments color each by one
            res[color]++;

            // Length of all yellow triangles 
            // res.yellow

         
      }
      return res;
}
```

```css
canvas {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
}

.tally {
  position: fixed;
  width: 50px;
  left: 255px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.6.3/fabric.js"></script>

<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="green" onclick="iconSet()" />Green &emsp;
<input class="tally" disabled id="greentally" type="text" value="0">
<br>
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="yellow" onclick="iconSet()" /> Yellow &emsp;
<input class="tally" disabled id="yellowtally" type="text" value="0">
<br>
<input name="iconType" type="radio" id="red" onclick="iconSet()" /> red &emsp;
<input class="tally" disabled id="redtally" type="text" value="0">
<canvas id="c" width="300" height="300"></canvas>
```

NOTE:: I was not able to fix  `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'top' of null` ERROR.

Comment: This is a good solution, but I found the count is still triggered when moving an icon, not just when placing one.